# Scanner execution failure post Sonar upgrade from 4.4.1 to 5.3

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube5.3

We are facing below error post upgrade to Sonar 5.3 . We did upgrade from 4.4.1 to 4.5.6 and later from 4.5.6 to 5.3 without issues. We have updated sonar-runner from version 2.3 to sonar-scanner-2.5 . Can someone advise please?

Also,we have updated below plugins:
                sonar-checkstyle-plugin-2.1.1.jar -> sonar-checkstyle-plugin-2.4.jar
                sonar-java-plugin-2.5.1.jar -> sonar-java-plugin-3.7.1.jar
                sonar-csharp-plugin-3.3.jar -> sonar-csharp-plugin-4.4.jar

Below is our current plugin list:

```
            stylecop,sonar-stylecop-plugin-1.1.jar
            scmgit,sonar-scm-git-plugin-1.0.jar
            python,sonar-python-plugin-1.3.jar
            visualstudio,sonar-visual-studio-plugin-1.2.jar
            scmsvn,sonar-scm-svn-plugin-1.2.jar
            dotnetndeps,sonar-dotnet-ndeps-plugin-2.1.jar
            dotnetgallio,sonar-dotnet-gallio-plugin-2.1.jar
            checkstyle,sonar-checkstyle-plugin-2.4.jar
            java,sonar-java-plugin-3.7.1.jar
            dotnet,sonar-dotnet-plugin-2.1.jar
            csharp,sonar-csharp-plugin-4.4.jar

            #########################################################################
            [12:14:01][Step 2/2] ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
            [12:14:01][Step 2/2] INFO: Final Memory: 41M/99M
            [12:14:01][Step 2/2] INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
            [12:14:01][Step 2/2] java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to register extension org.sonar.plugins.csharp.ndeps.sensor.NDepsSensor
            [12:14:01][Step 2/2]    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.addExtension(ComponentContainer.java:238)
            [12:14:01][Step 2/2]    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.ExtensionInstaller.doInstall(ExtensionInstaller.java:72)
            [12:14:01][Step 2/2]    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.ExtensionInstaller.install(ExtensionInstaller.java:52)
            [12:14:01][Step 2/2]    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.addExtensions(ModuleScanContainer.java:172)
            [12:14:01][Step 2/2]    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doBeforeStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:92)
            [12:14:01][Step 2/2]    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:130)
            [12:14:01][Step 2/2]    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:117)
            [12:14:01][Step 2/2]    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:243)
            [12:14:01][Step 2/2]    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:238)
            [12:14:01][Step 2/2]    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:236)
            [12:14:01][Step 2/2]    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:228)
            [12:14:01][Step 2/2]    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:132)
            [12:14:01][Step 2/2]    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:117)
            [12:14:01][Step 2/2]    at org.sonar.batch.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:55)
            [12:14:01][Step 2/2]    at org.sonar.batch.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:86)
            [12:14:01][Step 2/2]    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:132)
            [12:14:01][Step 2/2]    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:117)
            [12:14:01][Step 2/2]    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:122)
            [12:14:01][Step 2/2]    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:119)
            [12:14:01][Step 2/2]    at org.sonar.runner.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:67)
            [12:14:01][Step 2/2]    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            [12:14:01][Step 2/2]    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
            [12:14:01][Step 2/2]    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            [12:14:01][Step 2/2]    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
            [12:14:01][Step 2/2]    at org.sonar.runner.impl.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:61)
            [12:14:01][Step 2/2]    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
            [12:14:01][Step 2/2]    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:274)
            [12:14:01][Step 2/2]    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedRunner.java:165)
            [12:14:01][Step 2/2]    at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedRunner.java:152)
            [12:14:01][Step 2/2]    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.runAnalysis(Main.java:118)
            [12:14:01][Step 2/2]    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:80)
            [12:14:01][Step 2/2]    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:66)
            [12:14:01][Step 2/2] Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/sonar/api/resources/ProjectFileSystem;
            [12:14:01][Step 2/2]    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
            [12:14:01][Step 2/2]    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2387)
            [12:14:01][Step 2/2]    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1796)
            [12:14:01][Step 2/2]    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AdaptingInjection$2.run(AdaptingInjection.java:217)
            [12:14:01][Step 2/2]    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            [12:14:01][Step 2/2]    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AdaptingInjection.injectionFieldAnnotated(AdaptingInjection.java:209)
            [12:14:01][Step 2/2]    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AdaptingInjection.fieldAnnotatedInjectionAdapter(AdaptingInjection.java:188)
            [12:14:01][Step 2/2]    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AdaptingInjection.createComponentAdapter(AdaptingInjection.java:57)
            [12:14:01][Step 2/2]    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehaviorFactory.createComponentAdapter(AbstractBehaviorFactory.java:44)
            [12:14:01][Step 2/2]    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.OptInCaching.createComponentAdapter(OptInCaching.java:45)
            [12:14:01][Step 2/2]    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.addComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:536)
            [12:14:01][Step 2/2]    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.access$300(DefaultPicoContainer.java:84)
            [12:14:01][Step 2/2]    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer$AsPropertiesPicoContainer.addComponent(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1149)
            [12:14:01][Step 2/2]    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.addExtension(ComponentContainer.java:236)
            [12:14:01][Step 2/2]    ... 31 more
            [12:14:01][Step 2/2] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sonar.api.resources.ProjectFileSystem
            [12:14:01][Step 2/2]    at org.sonar.classloader.ParentFirstStrategy.loadClass(ParentFirstStrategy.java:39)
            [12:14:01][Step 2/2]    at org.sonar.classloader.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:87)
            [12:14:01][Step 2/2]    at org.sonar.classloader.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:76)
            [12:14:01][Step 2/2]    ... 45 more
            [12:14:01][Step 2/2] Process exited with code 1
            [12:14:01][Step 2/2] Step SonarRunner (Command Line) failed
```

Comment: I have removed some plugins and it seems good. I will check more on this and update.

Comment: Seems the issues were due to old plugins. I have just kept below plugins for now:
scmgit,sonar-scm-git-plugin-1.0.jar 
scmsvn,sonar-scm-svn-plugin-1.2.jar
java,sonar-java-plugin-3.7.1.jar
csharp,sonar-csharp-plugin-4.4.jar